# Bandwidth of combined switch and router

Tags: switch, router, lan

I want to build a HTPC (*Home Theater PC*) connected to a NAS (*Network Access Storage*) server where all the media will be.

My HTPC and NAS server will be connected to a Gigabit Ethernet switch, and this switch will be connected to a Fast Ethernet router which provides internet from the ISP.

My question is: **will the connection between the HTPC and the NAS have a Gigabit (1000Mb) or Fast (100Mb) bandwidth?**

If I'm not wrong, when the HTPC will try to access the NAS server, it will do it directly through the switch, and therefore with Gigabit Ethernet connection (1000Mb of bandwidth).

However, when the HTPC will try to access the internet (or other device connected to the router), it will do it through the switch and then the router, and therefore with Fast Ethernet connection (100Mb of bandwidth).

When someone will try to access the NAS from, lets say, the Wifi provided by the router, it will do it through router then switch, and therefore at a bandwidth of 100Mb.

Is all this correct?

Comment: Questions about home networking and consumer-grade devices are off-topic for this forum. Please see the Help Center for which types of questions are allowed, and which types are not allowed. You can ask this question on Super User.

Comment: @RonMaupin Yes, just read. Flagging now.

Answer (score 1):

Shortly someone will tell you that questions about home networks are off topic and will give a link to the rules for this forum.

However, an Ethernet's link speed is always predicated upon the device it is plugged into at the physical and MAC layers. The IP (network) connection to some other device has no impact on your link speed. So, if your switch is Gigabit and the machines plugged into it have Gigabit interfaces then they should negotiate a Gigabit link speed. As you mentioned your router being FastE will negotiate a FastEthernet connection with the switch. Your wireless devices with always negotiate some link speed within the capabilities of whatever 802.xx protocol you are utilizing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And now that I read the help center I understand that, as you said, my question is off topic. Deleting now...

Comment: Please don't feed the bears. The site is for network professionals managing professional networks.